# How to confirm the nth Catalan Number given the first few values in the sequence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

Given $Y_0 = 1$, $Y_1 = 1$, $Y_2 = 2$, $Y_3 = 5$, $Y_4 = 14$, $Y_5 = 42$, $Y_6 = 132$; what are three different ways to confirm that $Y_r$ may possibly be the nth Catalan number for all $r$. Describe in detail and what are the advantages of each approach relative to the others.

Comment: Can you at least come up with one possible approach?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was thinking the explicit formula for Catalan numbers Cn = (2n choose n)(1/n+1)or maybe recursive formula but I'm not too sure how to word it or whether this is even correct. Thank you

Comment: also are approaches such as triangulations of polygons and mountain ranges valid or trivial in this case? Appreciate your help @BrianM.Scott

Comment: It’s a bit vague, but I suspect that the idea is that $Y_n$ is the number of objects of size $n$ of some particular type, you’ve discovered that the first few values of $Y_n$ are Catalan numbers, and the question is how you might proceed to try to prove this. One way would indeed be to try to prove directly that $Y_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$, and another would be to show that the numbers $Y_n$ satisfy one of the same recurrences as the Catalan numbers. And you’ve just identified a third possible approach: fine a bijection between whatever you’re counting and something like mountain ranges ...

Comment: ... that is known to follow the Catalan numbers. I think that you do have the right general idea, though you’ll still have to come up with advantages for the different approaches, and I really have no idea off the top of my head what might be wanted there.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How would I go about showing that the number Yn satisfies one of the same recurrences as the Catalan numbers and what is meant by recurrences

Comment: Sometimes the objects that you’re counting have a structure that lends itself to analysis in terms of, for instance, the identity $$C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}\;;$$ this is the case with triangulations of an $(n+2)$-gon and with full binary trees with $n+1$ leaves.